# How can i use enum,switch,case and return to decide when to use Animator states?

Tags: c#, enums, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Animations : MonoBehaviour {

    public enum AnimatorStates
    {
        WALK, RUN, IDLE
    }

    private static Animator _anim;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        _anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    private static  AnimStates(AnimatorStates states)
    {
        switch (states)
        {
            case AnimatorStates.IDLE:
                return _anim.Play("idle");
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void LateUpdate ()
    {

    }
}
```

The first problem is what type should be return ? After the static:

```
private static  AnimStates(AnimatorStates states)
```

Second problem is how do i use it after creating the cases in the LateUpdate if i'm not wrong i should call the animations from inside the LateUpdate or Update function ?

And last how can i use this script later from another script ? 
Just for example just for the logic not a real code if in another script i will make something like:

```
if (text == "walk")
    Animations.walk
```

This kind of logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I gather you don't need `_anim` or `AnimStates` marked as static. In this case I would imagine something like the code below would do it for you.

```
public class Animations : MonoBehaviour
{
    public enum AnimatorStates
    {
        WALK, RUN, IDLE
    }

    private Animator _anim;

    void Start()
    {
        _anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    private void PlayState(AnimatorStates state)
    {
        string animName = string.Empty;
        switch (state)
        {
            case AnimatorStates.IDLE:
                animName = "idle";
                break;
        }
        _anim.Play(animName);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) {
            PlayState(AnimatorStates.IDLE);
        }
    }
}
```